# Connect to mysql database on specific PC on network using static IP

Tags: java, mysql, database, networking

How to connect to specific mysql database on PC inside network, the whole PCs in the network using fixed internet IP address, but each one have its own network IP

the command line like this
databaseServer=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx:(Port Number)

how to modify this line using both of internet IP and network IP to reach the database to connect to it?
Also the router configuration may be not accessible, blocked login from ISP.

thanks

Comment: this is the  command line whos telling the app the database URL

databaseServer=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx\:(Port Number)

Comment: you can use either the public ip or the private ip of the PC that is running mysql.